# Get selected items in a popSelect with PHP

Tags: php, forms, jquery-plugins

I am using the popSelect jquery plugin (http://jquer.in/popSelect/)
This is the code I use :

```
<select name="tun" id="tun" class="form-control">
   <option value='op1'>op1</option>
   <option value='op2'>op2</option>
   <option value='op3'>op3</option>
   <option value='op4'>op4</option>
</select>
```

And this is the javascript code to run the plugin

```
$('#tun').popSelect({
    placeholderText: 'tun',
    showTitle: false ,
    autoIncrease: true
  });
```

I want to get the selected items once the form is submitted (post). I tried this but I got an empty array.

```
$tun=$_POST['tun']
```

In the documentation they said that this code allow to returns the current selected values.

```
$(elem).popSelect('value')
```

This is with javascript, but I want these elements in my PHP code.

Can someone help me ?.

Comment: Can you post some code or a link to the plugin ?

Comment: @AhmedWessam this is the link to the plugin: http://jquer.in/popSelect/.

Comment: Most probably you're getting an undefined variable error. its `$_POST['tun']`, not `$POST_['tun']`. Also try to print the whole post request array using `print_r($_POST);` and see what you actually receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume you have the following form:

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  Select a color: 
  <select id="myselect" name="colors[]" multiple>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="violet">Violet</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="white" selected="selected">White</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And you have initialized the popSelect plugin in javascript as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#myselect").popSelect({
        showTitle: false,
        maxAllowed: 4
    });
});
```

Then, inside your `welcome.php` file you can fetch what the user has selected by accessing the `$_POST` array variable of the post request:

```
$colorsSelected = $_POST['colors'];
```

Comment: OK, please update your question with your code, so we can troubleshoot this.

Comment: @Massi I dont know if its a typo when you've pasted it here, but its `$_POST`, not `$POST_`. Also try to `print_r($_POST);` the whole request array and see what you've got.

Comment: Yes it's $_POST, I Edited the question.The print_r($_POST['tun']) gave me the last etem selected and not all the etems selected.

Comment: Great. Then if you wish to use a multiple select you'll have to change its name attribute to `tun[]` in your form's HTML, to mark it as an array. Check my example with the brackets in `name="colors[]"` above. That way you will receive all the options selected and not only the last one.